# Linux Ubuntu MATE 14.04.1 Connection Issues

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, mate

I recently dual-booted Ubuntu MATE (14.04.1) alongside regular Ubuntu (14.04.1). Regular Ubuntu was able to connect to the Internet. Ubuntu MATE is having issues. It seems that the Wi-Fi is not on, at all! I've searched the internet (including here), but none of the suggestions I've seen online have worked. I took some screenshots of what my desktop looks like:

[image]

**Fig. 1** This is what the top-right corner looks like with the icon for connections.

By left-clicking I had the option to enable/disable Networking. This is what comes up when I enable/disable.

[image]

**Fig. 2** This came up whether I was enabling or disabling networking.

The only options I have (that aren't greyed out) when I left-click on the network icon are: VPN Connections, Enable Networking (toggle), Edit. When I right-click, the options are: About, Lock To Panel. I've played around with these, with no progress.

There's a button on the keyboard (same key as F2) that look's like an antenna. I press it (on regular Ubuntu, it seems to be the Wi-Fi enable key) and the Bluetooth will toggle on/off, and the Bluetooth icon will appear/disappear from the top-right corner.

My only guess is that it's something wrong with my computer (weird Wi-Fi/Bluetooth key; missing drivers maybe; etc.), Ubuntu MATE (doubtful, because I'm sure others have it running fine on their machines), some file is missing from the system, or I did something wrong in the dual-boot.

I was hoping some one may have had the same exact issue, and could point me to the root of the problem.

I have a Dell Inspiron 1440, if that helps. Originally had 3GB of RAM and Windows 7. I've seen overwritten Windows 7 with these two versions of Ubuntu and now it has a total of 8GB of RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I noticed I had some weird messages appearing prior to the login screen on every boot. Here's an example picture:

[image]

Here's what it says (based on my blurry pictures):

```
[13.198589] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode15.fw" not found
[13.198591] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode15.fw" not found
[13.198592] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
```

I read the web page and followed the instructions. It led me to another web page where I was able to download the drivers.

Here's the web page, in case anyone is having a similar issue:

```
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware
```

I ended up here:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20Internet%20access
```

And just had to do two commands in the terminal to acquire the drivers:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

NOTE: I have the two commands up here as examples. Depending on your computer/Wi-Fi-card, you may have to go through a different set of steps/commands.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I've found some help on the issue:

https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/internet

On my other laptop (the one I'm using now and used to originally put up this question/thread) I have Windows 7 and Linux Mint MATE (version 17 or 17.1 I believe). Windows worked fine, but Linux didn't have access to the internet. It could connect to the router, but would never load pages.

I found this page on the web and tried the last fix listed. It refers to having Windows "let go" of the IP Address assigned to the computer (based on the unique MAC Address it has, that has to be shared by Windows and Linux). After making Windows "let go" of the IP Address, Linux was able to access the internet. I'm still having trouble with my laptop (for which I originally asked the question), but I'll try to see if any of the other suggestions on the website work. I'll post my results.